# Number of solutions to diophantine equation involving products

Tags: group-theory, diophantine-equations

How do we solve the following Diophantine equation?

> Find the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 3^{11}\cdot5^{9}\cdot7^{7}\cdot11^{5}$ where $x_1 \le x_2\le  x_3\le  x_4$.

For equations involving sums, that's easy, but for products, I have no idea.
Any idea or suggestion will be welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: any of the number has to be of the form $x_i=3^{a_i}\cdot{5^{b_i}}\cdot{7^{c_i}}\cdot{11^{d_i}}$. Think what are the equations you can write based on that.

Comment: @Galc127: I know that $\sum{a_i}=11,\sum{b_i}=9,...$, but I can't proceed further with that.

Comment: Why not? do you know how to find the number of non negative solutions to any of this four equations?

Comment: @Galc127: I also need the condition that $x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4$, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: when you have equations for $a_{i},b_{i}$ and others, look here :[Stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)